# Passing variables through php and jquery in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, parameter-passing

I am using wordpress and have the following code on functions.php file

```
function fun1() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'aldi_code', 'wp-content/uploads/custom-css-js/675.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

 wp_localize_script( 'aldi_code', 'test', array(
     'current_user' => wp_get_current_user()
 ) ) ;
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fun1' );
```

I want to access the value of `current_user` from `wp_admin` through jquery using the following code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    
    var displayName = test.current_user.display_name;       
});
```

The problem is that I get the error:

> test is not defined.

Do you have any idea what is wrong on this code??

Comment: Is the `document.ready` function inside the `wp-content/uploads/custom-css-js/675.js` file?

Comment: The 675.js file has only the this code 

`jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    
    var displayName = test.current_user.display_name;       
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on how you're passing the `current_user` object to the jQuery.  Your jQuery should look like this to get `display_name`.

To see what is passed to `current_user` in the JS.  Just go to the developer's console and type in `test.current_user` and you'll see that `data` is where the userdata is stored as an object.

You also don't need to use `document(ready)` - for whatever that's worth.

```
jQuery(
    function($){
        let display_name = test.current_user.data.display_name;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna pass values between JS and PHP directly, you can use `cookies`. Both of them can read and write data in there.
Set a cookie in PHP, then read it in JS.